# torch.version.cuda is None in certain version of pytorch and cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

My cuda version is shown here.
[nvcc -V output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AxRR.png)
[nvidia-smi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTBjh.png)

I basically want to install apex. I first use command

```
conda install pytorch=1.10.1 cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch
```

to install torch with cuda, and this version of cudatoolkit works fine and

```
torch.version.cuda
```

correctly shows the expected output "11.1" and

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

returns True. However, this doesn't work when later I'm trying to install apex because the version of my nvcc -V as shown above is 11.4 yet the cudatoolkit is 11.1.

Then I use command

```
conda install pytorch cudatoolkit=11.4 -c pytorch
```

to install the right version 11.4 of cudatoolkit. After doing this, the torch version becomes 1.9.1. However,

```
torch.version.cuda
```

becomes None and

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

returns False.

I've also tried cudatoolkit=11.4 with torch version 1.9.1 and 1.12.1, and none of them works either.

I expect my GPU to be detected correctly. What version of torch and cudatoolkit should I use? Or is anything else wrong here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: torch.version.cuda  Returning None  means you have installed a version a Pytorch which doesn't have built in GPU acceleration. Try again.

Comment: @talonmies Do you remember where/how you read/learned that?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and using pip to install solved my problem.

```
    pip3 install torch==1.10.1+cu113 torchvision==0.11.2+cu113 torchaudio==0.10.1+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
```